# Windows Media foundation multiple video renderer in EVR

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

I am exploring windows media foundation.

I have created one example application as described in below link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703190(v=vs.85).aspx

But I am using two video sources and I have also added two video renderer in the topology, in method `CreateMediaSinkActivate` by calling :

```
MFCreateVideoRendererActivate(hVideoWindow, &pActivate); <-- Two times for each video
```

Now I see two video are getting displayed in one window with flickering, which is expected.

In the callback `OnTopologyStatus` I am adjusting size of the first video:

```
(void)MFGetService(pSession, MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pVideoDisplay));
RECT rcDest = { 0, 0, 200, 200 };
HRESULT hr = pVideoDisplay->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &rcDest);
```

And on the screen I can seen one video on the top with 200x200 window and one video in the background in full screen window.

How can I adjust size of the other video window, which is in full screen in background.

Comment: I think the media session just can pass the first video renderer service. If  you use two times MFCreateVideoRendererActivate on the same hVideoWindow, you will get always flickering i think. You have to use two different hVideoWindow, or use the video mixing component of the EVR.

Comment: @mofo77 : Thanks for replay, If I use two `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate` I see flickering effect which is expected, But how can I mix two video, is there any why of doing it. As I never get access to 2nd renderer. Also I tried to add single `MFCreateVideoRendererActivate ` and then added second stream by using `AddStreamSink` but then I get `0xC00D4A3B -- MF_E_STREAMSINKS_FIXED` error. Some how I am not able to display two video streams properly. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try MediaSink::GetCharacteristics, EVR should not return MF_E_STREAMSINKS_FIXED.

Comment: I did `hrMS = pMediaSink->GetCharacteristics(&sinkCharacteristics);` and I get only `MEDIASINK_CLOCK_REQUIRED` and `MEDIASINK_CAN_PREROLL` flags are set. And I don't see flag `MF_E_STREAMSINKS_FIXED` set.

Comment: Also when I call `pMediaSink->AddStreamSink(iStream, NULL, &pStreamSink);` then I don't get any error but none of the videos I see in the renderer (iStream variable runs from 0-3 out of which 1 and 3 is video stream and 0 and 2 audio streams). I think some mistake in `AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, iStream, &pOutputNode);` or `pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(iStream, pOutputNode, iStream);` which is causing the issue.